# Import a file during runtime in Android using Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, file-io

I'm trying to import a file during runtime. I put a file `f8.csv` in this location on android `Internal storage\Android\data\com.site.myapp\files`

The user types the file name in the input field, I get the file name and then 
Then I try to access it using this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class ReadAFile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField fileName;
    public static volatile string file_name;
    FileInfo f1;
    public static volatile string message1, message2, message3, path;
    public static volatile string file_content;



    public void MyLoad()
    {
        file_name = fileName.text.ToString();
        f1 = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + file_name);
        if (f1.Exists)
        {

            StreamReader r = File.OpenText(Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + file_name);
            string info = r.ReadToEnd();
            r.Close();
            message1 = "Content of the file is: " + info;
        }
        else
        {
            message1 = "File not found!";
        }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but this doesn't work. It doesn't work with a text file. It doesn't work if I change `persistentDataPath` to just `dataPath`

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: try using a forward slash in the path instead of a backslash

Comment: @lockstock file doesn't found on all occasions

Comment: @lockstock it didn't work with the forward slash

Comment: how about creating the file in code?

Comment: @lockstock what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve what I needed using WWW. I changed the location  of my text file as well.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;


public class ImageRead : MonoBehaviour {

    string url;

    public void readmyurl()
    {

           url = "file:///sdcard/Android/data/f8.txt";


    }

    private void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(file_read());

    }

    IEnumerator file_read()
    {
        readmyurl();
        yield return 0;
        WWW imgLink = new WWW(url);
        yield return imgLink;
        message1 = imgLink.text; //message1 is the content of file f8

    }



}
```